# Rearrange Legend in SAS

Tags: sas, legend

Legend is automatically alphabetical, and I would like to place the "No Data" category after the categorical Quartile Range.

```
proc gmap
data= library.df
map= library.vafips all;
id fips;
choro PredRateQuartile;
run;
quit;
```

[Map from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwFxP.png)

DATA SET

| FIPS | predictedRate | RateQuartile | (or RateQuartile) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51001 | 12.25494616 | 3 | Between 11% to 14% |
| 51003 | 15.68784651 | 4 | Over 14% |
| 51005 | 8.684354655 | 1 | Below 9% |
| 51007 | 0 | 0 | No Data |

With both Rate Quartile formattings, they are character due to whatever the if/then statement is doing to categorize them that way

Comment: Is that variable numeric or character?

Comment: It's categorical.  I used an if/then statement to classify the ranges so that it had the wording that I wanted. But now the "Over x%" comes after the "No data" category due to the legend going alphabetically.  I need help in how to override the alphabetical default in order to put the "No data" label at the end, instead of second to last.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: "categorical" is not a SAS type.  SAS only has numbers and character strings.  Try making your categories as numbers and attach a user defined format to the variable and see if the legend is generated in the order of actual numeric values instead of the displayed character strings.

Comment: They are character strings

Comment: I have also tried categorizing the Quartiles into numeric, 1 2 3 4 & 0, then using the PROC FORMAT value  0=No Data, 1= Under x%... and the Legend then still says 0,1,2,3,4 instead of the words that I want

Comment: Share a working example dataset.  Does not need to include all of your data (or even your real data).  Just enough so others can recreate the issue.

Comment: From the documentation you can set the order with ORDER=(value-list) on the LEGEND statement.

Comment: proc gmap
data=lib.data
map=lib.vafips ALL;
id fips;
choro RateQuartile; 
Legend ORDER=("Below 8.1%" "Between 8.1% and 10.8%" "Between 10.8% and 14.3%" "Over 14.3%" "No Data");run;
quit;

Comment: That code ran without errors but did nothing to change the order of the legend.  "No Data" is still before "Over x%"

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to prefix the `No Data` value with a hard space character (`"A0"x`).

How is the format for `PreDateQuartile` defined ?

Comment: Now "No Data" says "A0No Data" "A0 No Data" or " "A0" No Data"

Comment: It's a character string

Answer (score 1):

I was able to order the values using LEGEND by using a numeric variable.

Here I have modified an example from the documentation to create a simple integer variable.  So the example used POP variable (population in millions) to color the regions on the graph.  It left the grouping up to GMAP to decide.

So I created an integer POP2 variable and used that instead.

```
if pop > 21000000 then pop2 = 6;
else if pop > 10000000 then pop2=5;
else if pop > 5500000 then pop2=4;
else if pop > 4000000 then pop2=3;
else if pop > 2000000 then pop2=2;
else pop2=1;
```

Then I made a LEGEND statement to put them into some random order

```
legend1
  order=(3 4 5 2 1) 
  value=('4m - 5.5m' '5.5m - 10m' '21m +' '2m - 4m' '<2m')
;
```

And then replaced POP with POP2 in the CHORO statement and told it to use LEGEND1.

```
choro pop2 / cdefault=yellow stat=first legend=legend1;
```

Result

[image]